# Entity Framework - Include / Reference / Collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation-properties

I was wondering why there are separate methods for populating navigation properties.

If I work on an entire set, i can call `Include` on either a property or a collection.

However, if I work on a single entity, there are two separate methods to call depending on whether the item is a collection (`Collection`) or single reference (`Reference`).

Is there any way around this - this is making things more complicated than I think is necessary. And could anyone explain why this was decided during designing EF?

EDIT

Looking into it further, the problem goes deeper. What I was trying to do is create a generic way to load collection/navigation properties on a single entity. This can be done easy enough on the whole set using Include. But the method signatures for `Reference` and `Collection` are slightly different.

Never mind, will have to scatter these calls around my app.

e.g.

```
dbSet<T>().Include(e => e.Property).Include(e => e.Collection).Include(e => e.Collection.Property)
```

all seem to work.

However the calls for the single entity are different:

```
context.Entry(entity).Reference(e => e.Property).Load();
context.Entry(entity).Reference(e => e.Property.Select(e => e.SubProperty)).Load();
context.Entry(entity).Collection(e => e.Collection).Load();
```

Comment: Care to explain how I can make this question better?

Comment: I didn't vote to close, but I did find it hard to understand the question first time around. Maybe it's worth adding some example code for Collection/Reference, then while referencing that an example of the call you would like to achieve?

Comment: I assume that by "work on a single entity" you mean using `context.Entry(entity).Collection("collection").Load()` method?

Comment: @Simon - you can improve this by showing us what you've tried, the errors you got and asking something specific.

Comment: The votes to close are because S/O is aimed more at questions that have specific answers eg "why is this code not working?/Because you forgot to use the X parameter". S/O specifically discourages questions that will provoke extended discussion (eg "what were they thinking when they designed feature X") - not because they aren't an interesting and useful question - but because S/O is not designed for that. Try asking on one of the computer-science related Stack Exchange sites instead :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only purpose of the `Include()` method is to explicitly eager load related data upon querying.

The `Entry()` method - on the other hand - is intended to give you specific control over the current state of an Entity attached to the context and not only `Load()` related data.

That is the reason why you have to explicitly choose between `Collection`, `Reference` and `Property` methods, each one exposes different set of functionality (hence returns different type).

For example:

- **Scalar** (`DbPropertyEntry`) contains the `IsModified` property that denotes whether the value changed from 'x' to 'y' (for example).
- **Reference** (`DbReferenceEntry`) contains the `IsLoaded` property that denotes whether the referenced data has been loaded from the database already.
- **Reference Collection** (`DbCollectionEntry`) derives from `ICollection` (hence `IEnumerable` as well) which means that you can iterate over its data. Yet, it cannot contain an `IsModified` property because it may differ for each item in the collection.

Still, if you're only interested in `Load()`, you can leverage the polymorphic `Member()` method (that returns `DbMemberEntry` that is the base type to all of the above types) and check if the entry is "Loadable":

```
var memberEntry = this.Entry(entity).Member("NavigationProperty");

if (memberEntry is DbCollectionEntry collectionMember)
    collectionMember.Load();

if (memberEntry is DbReferenceEntry referenceMember)
    referenceMember.Load();
```

Comment: Thanks @haim770 - the member function may help!

Comment: While partially helpful, the original question used expressions to reference the properties while the solution uses strings.  There isn't a simple way to translate one to the other unfortunately. If "Member" also took in a property expression this would have been the definitive solution but I'm still looking for it.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way:

1.- Load the entity including the collections:

```
MyClass myObject = dbContext.MyClasses
                    .Include(cls => cls.ObjectCollection)
                    .Single(cls => cls.Pk == entityPk);
```

2.- Then you must retrieve that object Entry and tell EF to load the required properties in the collection objects:

```
dbContext.Entry(myObject).Collection("ObjectCollection").Query().Include("ReferenceClass").Load();
```

Further reading:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue to support property expressions so that you can support "Include" syntax FindAsync, the following solution retrieves the PropertyInfo for the referred property then uses `Expression.Convert` so that you can now support the `context.Entry(entity).Member(e => e.Property).Load()` syntax you wished.

Add the following two classes to some namespace and `using` it in your class:

```
public class MemberEntry
{
    /// <summary>
    /// If this MemberEntry refers to a CollectionEntry, this will be not null
    /// </summary>
    public CollectionEntry? CollectionEntry { get; init; }
    /// <summary>
    /// If this MemberEntry refers to a ReferenceEntry, this will be not null
    /// </summary>
    public ReferenceEntry? ReferenceEntry { get; init; }
    public MemberEntry(CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
    {
        this.CollectionEntry = collectionEntry;
    }
    public MemberEntry(ReferenceEntry referenceEntry)
    {
        this.ReferenceEntry = referenceEntry;
    }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Loads the entity or entities referenced by this navigation property, unless Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.IsLoaded
    //     is already set to true.
    //     Note that entities that are already being tracked are not overwritten with new
    //     data from the database.
    public void Load()
    {
        if (this.CollectionEntry != null)
        {
            this.CollectionEntry.Load();
        }
        else
        {
            this.ReferenceEntry!.Load();
        }
    }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Loads the entity or entities referenced by this navigation property, unless Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.NavigationEntry.IsLoaded
    //     is already set to true.
    //     Note that entities that are already being tracked are not overwritten with new
    //     data from the database.
    //     Multiple active operations on the same context instance are not supported. Use
    //     'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling
    //     another method on this context.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   cancellationToken:
    //     A System.Threading.CancellationToken to observe while waiting for the task to
    //     complete.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A task that represents the asynchronous operation.
    public Task LoadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (this.CollectionEntry != null)
        {
            return this.CollectionEntry.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.ReferenceEntry!.LoadAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}

public static class EntityEntryExtensions
{
    public static MemberEntry Member<TEntity>(this EntityEntry<TEntity> entityEntry, Expression<Func<TEntity,object?>> prop)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var propInfo = GetPropertyInfo(prop);
        MemberEntry memberEntry;
        if (propInfo.PropertyType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEnumerable)))
        {
            Expression converted = Expression.Convert(prop.Body, typeof(IEnumerable<object>));
            Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<object>>> collProp = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<object>>>(converted, prop.Parameters);
            memberEntry = new(entityEntry.Collection(collProp));
        }
        else
        {
            memberEntry = new(entityEntry.Reference(prop));
        }
        return memberEntry;
    }
    
    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda)
    {
        Type type = typeof(TSource);
        if (propertyLambda.Body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
                propertyLambda.ToString()));
        if (propertyLambda.Body is MemberExpression member)
        {
            if (member.Member == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                    "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
                    propertyLambda.ToString()));
            if (member.Member is PropertyInfo propInfo)
            {
                if (type != propInfo.ReflectedType &&
                !type.IsSubclassOf(propInfo.ReflectedType!))
                    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                        "Expression '{0}' refers to a property that is not from type {1}.",
                        propertyLambda.ToString(),
                        type));
                else
                    return propInfo;
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                    "Expression '{0}' doesn't refer to a class property of {1}.",
                    propertyLambda.ToString(),
                type));
    }
}
```

Synchronous:

```
this.Entry(myObject).Member(_ => _.MyProperty).Load();
```

Asynchronous:

```
await this.Entry(myObject).Member(_ => _.MyProperty).LoadAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the referenced collection using Select.

```
db.MyObject.Include(x => x.RefObect.Select(y => y.RefRefObject));
```