# How to pass multiple properties to Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have an EF core that I am trying to "Include" some relations by key, and found an answer I can do it like this:

//Get entity by key first, then load relations for it like this:

```
await context.Entry(entity).Collection(expressions).LoadAsync();
```

This collection method takes:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expressions
```

All examples I have seen, is a way to pass a single property to it.

Here is the full code of a wrapper that I want:

```
    public static async Task<TEntity> FindInContextAsync<TEntity, TProperty>(object keyValue, Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> expressions)
        where TEntity : class where TProperty : class
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AccountsDbContext>();

        var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

        var Entit = await dbSet.FindAsync(keyValue);
        if (Entit == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(TEntity), keyValue);
        }

        await context.Entry(Entit).Collection(expressions).LoadAsync();

        return Entit;
    }
```

I would like to call it as cleanly and as little code as possible, something like this:

```
await FindInAccountsContextAsync<MyEntity, dynamic>(id, x => x.RelationClass1, x.RelationClass2...);
```

Seems like above would be more of a params case:

```
params Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>[] expressions
```

But then this would not get accepted by `Collection()`

In the end, I want to be able to retrieve any object from DbContext by key, with eager loading specified

Any solution is welcomed, as I can't get anything to work!

Answer (score 0):

`DbEntityEntry.Collection` takes:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationProperty
```

This is to select a single property of type `ICollection<TElement>`, not multiple properties.

Because `ICollection` is invariant, and `TElement` is likely going to be different for each navigation property, you aren't going to be able to pass a collection of these to `FindInContextAsync`.

The simplest workaround would be to remove the delegate and load the navigations after calling `FindInContextAsync`, but if you must pass delegates you could do this:

```
public static async Task<TEntity> FindInContextAsync<TEntity>(
    object keyValue,
    params Func<TEntity, Task>[] afterFind)
    where TEntity : class
{
    // ...

    var entity = await dbSet.FindAsync(keyValue);
    
    // ...

    await Task.WhenAll(afterFind.Select(func => func(entity)));

    return entity;
}
```

And call like this:

```
var entity = await FindInAccountsContextAsync(
    id,
    (MyEntity x) => context.Entry(x).Collection(y => y.RelationClass1).LoadAsync(),
    (MyEntity x) => context.Entry(x).Collection(y => y.RelationClass2).LoadAsync());
```

---

The above could be simplified slightly by adding a helper function:

```
Task LoadCollectionAsync<TEntity, TProperty>(
    TEntity entity,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, ICollection<TElement>>> navigationProperty)
{
    return context.Entry(entity).Collection(navigationProperty).LoadAsync();
}
```

Which would allow you to do this:

```
var entity = await FindInAccountsContextAsync(
    id,
    (MyEntity x) => LoadCollectionAsync(x, y => y.RelationClass1),
    (MyEntity x) => LoadCollectionAsync(x, y => y.RelationClass2));
```

Comment: Do you think I could do a loop to call Collection().LoadAsync() multiple times, where I pass a params of select functions? Except that don't know how to write them as <IEnumerable<TProperty>> That should shorten the FindInAccountsContextAsync()

Comment: If `DbEntityEntry.Collection` used `IEnumerable` rather than `ICollection` it would be possible, but `ICollection` is invariant and `TProperty` would need to be different each time.

Comment: Do the lambda parameters to `FindInAccountsContextAsync` really need to have their parameters explicitly typed? Couldn't you just use `FindInAccountsContextAsync<MyEntity>(`...?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake for thinking I need to use `Collection()`. I was able to achieve below using `Reference()` instead, which takes `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>` instead of IEnumerable which is what was causing me issues. Thanks to @NetMage, end result:

```
var entity = await FindInAccountsContextAsync<AccountCreditDebit>(
id, x => x.CreditDebitType, x => x.CreditDebitSource;
```

This allows me to pass any DbSet in my Account DB  Context (in this case AccountCreditDebit DbSet) and return the entity from DbSet with relations specified (CreditDebitType, CreditDebitSource).

Full Code:

```
       public static async Task<TEntity> FindInAccountsContextAsync<TEntity>(object keyValue, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] expressions)
        where TEntity : class where TProperty : class
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();

        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AccountsDbContext>();

        var dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();

        var entity = await dbSet.FindAsync(keyValue);
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(TEntity), keyValue);
        }

        foreach (var expression in expressions)
        {
            await context.Entry(entity).Reference(expression).LoadAsync();
        }
        

        return entity;
    }
```

The limitation I can think of, is I cannot pass a function if ICollection in the mix with single property such as:

```
var entity = await FindInAccountsContextAsync<AccountCreditDebit>(
id, 
x => x.CreditDebitType, /*<= Single property */ 
x => x.ManyCreditDebitSources; //<= A Collection
```

Old Comment answered in comments:

The only thing I would like to improve, is to remove this `dynamic` if possible

```
await FindInAccountsContextAsync<AccountCreditDebit, dynamic>(...)
```

Comment: You can replace `dynamic` with `object` which is probably the net effect in this case, but in that case you don't need a generic type parameter, just use `params Expression<Func<TEntity,object>>[] expressions`. I am thinking a better approach would be to use a single `Expression<Func<TEntity,TAnon>> expression` that expects the form `x => new { x.CreditDebitType, x.CreditDebitSource, x.ManyCreditDebitSources }`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18074711/2557128) seems like it is relevant to what you are trying to do and when you should use `Collection`/`Reference`/`Property` and implies you could just have `params string PropertyNames`

Comment: @NetMage Thanks for the object tip! I didn't know Reference would accept <TEntity, object> expression! However, I believe to do x => new{ x.1, x.2...) I would have to introduce the 2nd generic type parameter, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Yes, You would have a second type parameter, but you would not have to set either one - the compiler should be able to infer the types from the parameters. Also, why do you need the first type parameter? Doesn't it always have to be `AccoutnCreditDebit`?

Comment: @NetMage It doesn't. It can be anything - It's a DbSet of a DbContext. As DbContext (accounts) have multiple DbSets (tables), this allows me to choose the tabes.