# Generic method to retrieve DbSet <T> from DbContext and Using Include() method c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I made this function that retrieves all the data.

```cs
public static List<Volunteer> GetAllVolunteers()
{
    using (VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1 db = new VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1())
    {
        return db.Volunteers.**Include(v => v.roleForVolunteers).Include(v => v.VolunteerOffers)
                         .Include("VolunteerOffers.daysForAVolunteers")**.ToList();
    }
}
```

And I have this generic function that retrieves DBSet T.

```cs
public static List<T> GetDbSet<T>() where T : class
{
    using (VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1 db = new VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1())
    {
        return db.GetDbSet<T>().ToList();
    }
}
```

Can I make a generic function that will retrieve all the data that connect to one DBSet T?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework - Include / Reference / Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072243/entity-framework-include-reference-collection)

Comment: I did not quite understand how to adapt it to me

Comment: You need to use Reflection for extract all your Property from T that can include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
This is the solution that worked for me.

```
  public static List<T> GetDbSetWithIncludes<T>(string[] includes) where T : class
    {
        using (VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1 db = new VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1())
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            return IncludeMultiple<T>(db.GetDbSet<T>(), includes).ToList();
        }
    }


 public static IQueryable<T> IncludeMultiple<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string[] includes)where T : class
        {
            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) =>
                current.Include(include));
            }
            return query;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get `DbSet` for the `T` Entity Class Type from context as `DbSet<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`.

On this `IQueryable<T>` object can perform multiple operations like `Where()`, `Include()`, `orderBy()` etc with help of namespace `System.Linq`.

- With `Include()` method, pass on required included properties.
- For Parallel processing use TPL from `System.Threading.Tasks`

Try this:

```
public static List<T> GetDbSet<T>(string[] includeProperties) where T : class
{
    using (VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1 db = new VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1())
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = db.Set<T>();

        Parallel.ForEach(inlcudeProperties, includeProperty => {
           query.Include(includeProperty);
        });

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm grateful
Can you maybe tell me how I also give a Include of two levels?                  
i made this array for example:
        public static string[] include { get; set; } = { "roleForVolunteers", "VolunteerOffers", " VolunteerOffers.daysForAVolunteers " };
and this:   VolunteerOffers.daysForAVolunteers gave me an error

Comment: have VolunteerOffers be virtual property in T class and exclude that item from list. So you can be able to access that daysForVolunteers from virtual property

Comment: VolunteerOffers is virtual already

Comment: public static string[] include { get; set; } = [ "roleForVolunteers", "VolunteerOffers" ];

Comment: If you need this, you can try change string[] parameter with `IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> includesFunc`  and then `includesFunc(query)`

Comment: thanks, but i don't understand on what the error

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The context cannot be used while the model is being created....

Comment: Add MultipleActiveResultSets=true in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Some month ago i try to do somthing like that, but i have tableName. I leave you some detail, that you can adapt

You extract form context all your table and select only the ClrType corrispond with your T type.

```
var selectedTable = contextDb.Model
            .GetEntityTypes()
            .Select(x => new TableSpecification // Custom class
            {
                TableName = x.GetTableName(),
                ClrType = x.ClrType,
                JoinTable = x.GetForeignKeys(),
                JoinTableProp = x.GetForeignKeyProperties(),
                NavigationProp = x.GetNavigations(),
                ColumnsTable = null
            })
           .Where(// where ClrType)
           .Distinct()
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is my custom class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Seac.CRM.DbInfrastructure.Model.Context;

public class TableSpecification
{
    public string TableName { get; init; }
    public Type ClrType { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<IForeignKey> JoinTable { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<IProperty> JoinTableProp { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<INavigation> NavigationProp { get; init; }
    public IEnumerable<IProperty> ColumnsTable { get; init; }
}
```

then you can extract all your reference property

```
var joinLookup = selectedTable.JoinTable.GetLookupForeignKey();

foreach (var lookup in joinLookup)
   queryable = queryable.Include(lookup.PrincipalEntityType.Name.Split(".").Last());
```

I wish that can help you.

*** **EDIT**

If you need a custom include of T you can use `IIncludableQueryable<T, object>>`

```
public static List<T> GetDbSet<T>(IIncludableQueryable<T, object>> include = null) where T : class
{
    using (VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1 db = new VolunteerPlacementSystemDBEntities1())
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = db.Set<T>();

        if (includesFunc is not null)
            query = includesFunc(query);

        return query.ToList();
    }
}
```